# fabric js canvas tab not working with calcOffset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

i am using fabric js with ionic framework , with tabs and canvas in all tab view

issue if that if i reload tab with canvas that particular canvas work where as other canvas on next tab does not work i tried to call **"calcOffset"** on tab click .

Below is my code

```
jQuery( "a.tab-item" ).click(function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        canvas.calcOffset();canvas.renderAll();
        canvas1.calcOffset();canvas1.renderAll();
    });
```

link of my code on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QygEaZ

To replicate issue:
1: open 
http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5e1bcbe77d401481158ec7c658b545cd1452513640770/index.html#/tab/tab1

here tab 1 is active with canvas1

when u click tab 2 u can not see color in canvas2 means calcOffset not works

2: open 
http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5e1bcbe77d401481158ec7c658b545cd1452513640770/index.html#/tab/tab2

here tab 2 is active with canvas2

when u click tab 1 u can not see color in canvas1 means calcOffset not works

Comment: What do you mean by dont work?

Comment: click tab 1 u can see color of canvas , now when u click tab 2 canavas does not have background color